# How to make helper-generated HTML to work with jQuery (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

In order to fix a text duplication bug with `contenteditable` areas and Meteor I did following:

**document_page.js:**

```
Template.documentPage.helpers({
  contenteditable: function() {
    return '<div class="content" contenteditable="true">' + this.content + '</div>' 
  },
```

**document_page.html:**

```
<div class="editor">
  <input class="title" type="text" value="{{title}}">
  {{{contenteditable}}}
</div>
```

The problem now is jQuery no longer works with the HTML generated by `{{contenteditable}}`

Example:

```
Template.documentPage.rendered = function() {
   $('.content').addClass('test') // <--this does nothing
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: the code works what its the problem?

Comment: @Ethaan No, it doesn't work for me. I `.addClass` doesn't add anything to `.content`

Comment: i will undelete my answer and take a look on the photos ok?, done you are not getting that?

Comment: @Ethaan did you use `contenteditable: function() {
    return '<div class="content" contenteditable="true">' + this.content + '</div>' 
  },` do generate the `contenteditable` area?

Comment: this.content dosnt exist i just add  `+ 'first text click to edit'+`, check update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi alex the code actually works, just remove `+`this.content' +`to +`'click to start editing on the div' +`, since you are creating the object without content.

We replace this.content with this.

```
var finde = Documents.findOne({_id:this._id})
return '<div class="content" contenteditable="true">' +finde.content + '</div>'
```

And put the Template where this helper is used inside a waitOn on the Route.

```
waitOn:function(){
  if(this.ready()){
    //render the template
   }else{
    //render the loading template
  }
}
```

if you `console.log(this)`.

You will get `object {}`.

Comment: Could have put it into comments.

Comment: im going to delete this answer don't worry i just want alex to look at images, to figure out where is the problem so we can help him

Comment: @Ethaan Hey, you're right. But then how can I add my `this.content`? I need the `contenteditable` to show my `Document`'s content.

Comment: well just replace this.content to `'text' save/run` and overwritte text click outside the div and the new content is there, if you inspect the element the new content is there, since the div is editable its kinda reactive by itself

Comment: @Ethaan Yes, but if I hit page refresh the content will revert to `'text'`.

Comment: Well im stuck, do you really don't want to use  `<div contenteditable='true'>`? haha im still trying to figure out

Comment: @Ethaan Ha, thanks a lot. Yes, I need that. I think the problem is that `this.content` is causing a little. So when the jQuery in rendered fires, the `<div contenteditable='true'>` isn't actually rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69715/discussion-between-ethaan-and-alexchenco).

Comment: @alexchenco i find the solution to the "undefined" error